# RestKit: prevent getObjectsAtPath from mapping the same object twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am trying to work around a performance issue in my app. I am loading some objects from JSON using `RestKit` and `getObjectsAtPath`. Sometimes I get hundreds of objects from the server including nested relationships. So the mapping takes time and I know there is not much I can do.

Yet, if I call `getObjectsAtPath` multiple times and the server returns the same objects, I am under the impression that `RestKit` will try to re-map the same objects every time.

It makes sense since `RestKit` can't know whether an object has changed or not before it is mapped. But in my specific case it is a pity since I know these objects never change.

Is there a way to force `RestKit` to not re-map two objects with the same `identificationAttributes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't prevent the same object from being mapped twice, but the performance impact is similar to checking for a change on the client side anyway. What you should really be doing is passing something like a 'last request date' to the server so that it can filter and only return the appropriate content.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Let's say the client request A is "give me all the cities >200k inhabitants in England", then, later, B: "give me all the cities >100k inhabitants in England". There is an overlap. Yet, when it answers to B, the server has no idea it answered to A for the same client before. So it will resend the same stuff. Maybe a solution is to use the `setWillMapDeserializedResponseBlock` hook and manually "clean" the JSON payload on the client?

Comment: Ok, I see your duplicate data reason. You could do that, but the cost of searching and filtering kind of defeats the point (the benefit will be small). Better to send a list of ids that you want to exclude to the server if you can.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it is what I ended up doing. But just for the benefit of others: it might not work for everyone. I had to get the back end to accept POST requests instead of GET ones. In addition, keeping track on the client of the objects that have already been mapped is not straightforward at all (as far as I can tell).

Comment: You could run a fetch on the data store, returning an array of dictionaries containing only the ids (then get the array of id strings from that).

Comment: OK. I thought doing this would mean all the objects would get loaded every time - which I need to avoid. So I ended up storing the IDs separately (extracting them from the JSON payload).